# Erro de Login no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel

estou com problema no login do usuário no Laravel.

Vejam, ele não loga o usuário, mas também não retorna erro:

auth.php

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => 'Cliente',
    'table' => 'cliente',

    'reminder' => array(
        'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',
        'table' => 'password_reminders',
        'expire' => 60,
    ),
);
```

Meu Model
Cliente.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Cliente extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'cliente';
    protected $hidden   = array('password', 'remember_token');
    protected $fillable = [/*Meus campos*/];

    public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

Meu Controller
AuthController.php

```
class AuthController extends BaseController{

    public function __construct(){}
    public function postLogin(){
        $credentials = [
            'email'    => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        ];

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials,false)){
            return Redirect::to('/reserva');
        }

        return Redirect::to('/')
            ->with('message','Erro ao se logar, verifique o e-mail ou senha digitado.');
    }

    public function getLogout(){
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

Minha view:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'auth/login','method' => 'post']) }}
    @if(Session::has('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
    @endif

    {{ Form::text('email'); }}  
    {{ Form::password('password'); }}   
    {{ Form::submit('Acessar') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: No banco, os campos são respectivamente email e password na tabela cliente.

Comment: Vendo assim de cara ta certo! ele não emiti erros ?

Comment: Nenhum, se eu der um dd(Auth::attempt($credentials,false)) simplesmente me retorna false... ;(

Comment: você gerou a senha corretamente?

Answer (score 1):

Estou suspeitando que você não ta gravando a senha do usuário corretamente. Para gerar a senha do usuário precisa usar o [Hash:make](http://laravel.com/docs/security#storing-passwords).

```
Obs: Código abaixo é simplesmente para gravar o cadastro de usuários
```

```php
public function save() {
    if ((int) Input::get('id', 0) > 0) {
        $model = $this->repository->get(Input::get('id')); 
        if (((int)Input::get('password',0)) != 0){
            $model->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        }
    } else {
        $model = $this->repository->create();
        $model->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    }

    $model->admin    = Input::get('admin');
    $model->email    = Input::get('email');
    $model->username = Input::get('username');
    $model->namefull = Input::get('namefull');
    $model->active   = Input::get('active');
    $model->filialid = Input::get('filialid');

    if (ModelState::valid($model)) {
        $model->save();
        return Redirect::route('admin.user.update', array($model->id));
    } else {
        return Redirect::route('admin.user.update', array(Input::get('id', NULL)))->withErrors(ModelState::errors());
    }
}
```

Tem um ponto ai nessa linha `$model->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));` que precisa ser feito a senha com esse [Hash](http://laravel.com/docs/security#storing-passwords).

Verifique se a senha foi gerada assim, porque, se não no `Auth::attempt` retornará sempre falso.

Se for esse o problema, altere seu *script* [php](/questions/tagged/php) colocando [Hash::make](http://laravel.com/docs/security#storing-passwords) na gravação de senha e depois tente entrar pelo formulário de login novamente.

***Solução:***

Utilize [Auth::loginUsingId(1)](http://laravel.com/docs/security#manually), aonde o 1 é o numero que identifica o usuario na tabela de usuários e com isso ele ficará autenticado. Deve buscar os dados pelo [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent), exemplo:

```php
$cliente = Cliente::where('email', '=', $email)
                    ->where('password','=', $password)
                    ->first();
if ($cliente){
  //logado
  Auth::loginUsingId($cliente->id);
} else {
  // não foi encontrado,
}
```

Com isso todos os outros comandos funciona da mesma forma!

Referências:

- [Storing Passwords](http://laravel.com/docs/security#storing-passwords)
- [Accessing The Logged In User](http://laravel.com/docs/security#manually)
- [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

Comment: Então, a senha está sendo gravada e nesse ponto do sistema ela é gravada e autenticada sem hash mesmo. É um sistema do qual foi desenvolvido a algum tempo e ele não possui nenhuma criptografia na senha mesmo e eu estou migrando ele aos poucos, mas a senha nesse momento não pode autenticar com hash pois uma parte do sistema é feito em CodeIgniter.

Comment: Então realmente eu tinha razão, mas, o laravel existe uma forma de você autenticar o Id do usuário, fiz a edição com o item solução @EwertonMelo, é dessa forma

Comment: Vou testar aqui...

Comment: Por esse outro método também não rolou... :(

Comment: @EwertonMelo verifique sua aplicação e a parte de login porque funcionou comigo na minha aplicação esse comando, igual o anterior!

Comment: @EwertonMelo acho que ta faltando alguma coisa na sua aplicação ou um detalhe... ! é para funcionar deve ser sua base de dados ou na hora da pesquisa fica dificil eu dizer!

Comment: Estava fazendo uma revisão agora, desde o auth.php até a View. Fiz umas alterações pois o dono do sistema me passou que o login deve ser feito numa outra tabela, aproveitando a deixa, já coloquei o Hash::make() e pra autenticar o Hash::check('password',Input::get('password')), porém, não funciona mesmo assim, simplesmente ele retorna false. Eu sei q existe um comando que eu consigo ver a query que acabou de ser executado, vc se recorda qual é??? Assim fica mais fácil de debugar...

Comment: O comando eu achei...

Comment: Por exemplo, se eu visualizar a query executada por trás do Auth::attempt() ele me retorna isso: `string 'select * from `cliente_contato` where `email` = ? limit 1' (length=57)`

Comment: Não retornou o campo de password que é passado no array credentials...

Comment: Ele tem outro tipo de verificação internamente, mas, eu te passei um forma que pode ser usada normalmente

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido.

Um ponto importante, inicialmente eu tentei autenticar com a senha descriptografada, ele retornou false, isso ocorre pq internamente o método `attempt()` chama nativamente a verificação de hash `Hash::check()` então, nunca conseguiria autenticar o usuário sem um hash do Laravel. Com isso não existe a necessidade de fazer mais nada, só ter o hash criado. @HarryPotter, vc mencionou isso. Obrigado, mas de modo geral, a solução é mais simples do que eu imaginava.

Comment: Ewerton, então isso que você fez um texto é repetição do que eu falei logo abaixo?

Answer (score -1):

ContasController.php

```
public function postLogin(){
        $validator = Validator::make(input::all(), User::$rulesLogin);
        if( $validator->fails() ){
            return Redirect::route( 'home' )
                ->withErrors( $validator );
        } else {
            if(Auth::attempt(array(
                'username'     => Input::get('username'),
                'password'     => Input::get('password'),
                'active'    => 1
            ))){
                return Redirect::route('home');
            } else {
                return Redirect::route( 'home' )->with('global', 'conta/senha não confere');
            }
        }
    }
```

Contas.php Model

```
public static $rulesLogin = array(
                'username'      => 'required|max:50',
                'password'      => 'required|min:6'
        );
```

Comment: De novo: pode explicar *porquê* seu código resolve o problema? Confira o guia [answer].